# How can I see source for the current frame in LLDB without setting breakpoints?

Tags: debugging, lldb

When debugging a simple program with LLDB I do not see source for the current frame if I set the debugger to stop at entry, only assembly.

If a breakpoint is set, then I see source for each frame after hitting the breakpoint.

How can I see source for the current frame without setting breakpoints?

I want to follow the flow of a program without knowing which lines of code or functions are likely to be run.

Note that `list` does not suffice as it does not show the active line, just some source.

I'm debugging C++ code, I don't think that's important though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "current frame".

If you stop the program in the debugger (using breakpoints, or interrupting it) then you should see source for the frame you stopped at if it is a frame that has source.

But the debugger doesn't watch what your program is doing when it is running.  If it tried to do that it would interfere too much with the program execution, slowing it down, changing thread scheduling, etc.  The debugger tries very hard not to do that.

So it can't tell you what stack frames are executing in your program when it is not stopped.  There are other tools, e.g. sample, which use a time based stack sampling to show you broad outlines of program flow, though since these are just samples at some time interval they won't get all the details.

You can watch some subset of calls by putting auto-continue breakpoints on the calls, and having commands that do backtrace or source list.  Depending on how hot the calls you want to watch are, this may slow execution down quite a bit, however.

Comment: Does --stop-at-entry not stop?

Comment: Yes, it does, but that settings means "stop at program entry."  So if you run "process launch -s" then lldb will stop the process automatically once,  before any shared libraries are loaded or any code is executed.  That's a fairly uninteresting place to stop as far as stacks are concerned (there will be one thread in _dyld_start and that's all.)  This is really only if you have some work you need to do in the debugger before the target got to run at all.

Comment: Maybe you thought the "entry" referred to was "function entry"?  That is not the case.

Comment: Perhaps breaking at 'main' would do what I want then?

Comment: I am unclear what you are trying to achieve, can you describe your goal a little more clearly?

Comment: I want to step through program execution so I can see what's happening. I don't know where to start looking so the beginning seemed like a good start.

Comment: Most user code won't get run till main (static initializers being the exception.)  So starting at main should be fine.  But for programs of any complexity, stepping isn't a useful way to see the flow.  For instance most UI programs rely on callbacks from the UI toolkit, which get called somewhere in the event loop, and getting there by stepping would be very tedious.  And if code is dispatched to other threads, stepping won't get into that code.  It's generally better to pick a subset of functions you are curious about, and use breakpoints to see how they get called.